# Hyperledger Fabric v1.0 setup on multiple machines

Tags: hyperledger

I am working with balance transfer example I did setup in single machine I want to do that example in two machines.I am following the below link https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-samples/tree/release/balance-transfer can anyone tell me what are the steps or ways  I have to do for implementing that example in multiple machines.

Answer (score 2):

I was able to host hyperledger fabric network using docker swarm mode. Swarm mode provides a network across multiple hosts/machines for the communication of the fabric network components.

This post explains the deployment process https://medium.com/@wahabjawed/hyperledger-fabric-on-multiple-hosts-a33b08ef24f